# React-Native development: Why does android UI become unresponsive

Tags: android, react-native

I have to admit I am finding this react-native stuff very frustrating and flaky, though I've spent six solid weeks trying to get to grips.

However, the number one annoyance has to be that when developing using an android device or emulator at times the ui will become unresponsive and I end up starting again.

Currently I am trying to get to grips with bluetooth react-native-ble-manager, but that doesn't matter as it happens even with very simple apps that I am trying to learn with.

So, I create a new react-native app, using

```
npx react-native init test.
```

Then I cd to folder (windows 10)

Then I right click and start two command windows.

I have found that with a device I run

```
adb devices
adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081
```

(Not needed if using android emulator, which I start from Android Studio)

In one command window I type

```
npx react-native start to start the Metro packager.
```

When that is done on the other I type

```
npx react-native run-android
```

Hurrah I get my app on my phone (sometimes, it usually kicks off the second time, otherwise I end up doing a full reboot of laptop and phone - I told you it is very flaky.) and why do I have to jump through so many hoops? One command should be enough folks!!

Now, and using VS Code as my editor I make changes and watch as the app auto re-renders.

Except sometimes it doesn't, and sometimes it just fails. So start the r or d from metro windows. Often this restarts the app and I carry on.

However, and this occurs quite often, the app restarts, but the UI is totally unresponsive. By that I mean that buttons and/or TouchableOpacities won't respond to press or make sound or show the fadeout fadein.

I can restart the app, but still no ui response.

My only option is to run the npx react-native run-android again. Sometimes even that fails and I have to go back to the start of getting everything running again.

On  a large app I was working on I thought it might be a memory leak, but now as I said I'm working on a little test app and hardly even started it really.

Does anyone have any idea why the UI locks up?

Even more important to me, is anyone else experiencing such an awful development experience? Surely, if the peeps at Facebook were experiencing such awful behaviour they would have fixed it years ago?

I've tried all sorts of approaches, don't mention doing things from within VS Code, because that is an even worse experience.

I have spent probably more time fixing the development side of things than I have actually writing any code and I'm thoroughly disheartened by it all.

Sorry for the rant.

Comment: Is it just me then experiencing a lock up of UI?

Answer (score 0):

I freguently have the same issue. However, rather than restarting your android, it seems that simply closing the app and reopening will restart whatever process it is that allows the app to again be interacted with.